# How can I use my Car object references in a constructor?

Tags: java

I'm practicing making my own classes, and eventually I would like to make a fleet that contains these 3 cars and calculates the average MPG. I'm having trouble getting the cars into the carfleet. I think my problem is with the instance variables but I can't figure out what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CarFleet {

    Car car1;
    Car car2;
    Car car3;

    CarFleet(first, second, third) {
        car1 = first;
        car2 = second;
        car3 = third;
    }
}
```

---

```
class Car {

    double startMiles;
    double endMiles;
    double gallons;

    Car(double initialMiles, double endingMiles, double tankGals) {
        startMiles = initialMiles;
        endMiles = endingMiles;
        gallons = tankGals;
    }

    public double calculateMPG() {
        return (endMiles - startMiles) / gallons;
    }
}
```

---

```
class MPG {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Initial miles for trip: ");
        //double initMiles = scan.nextDouble();
        //System.out.println("End miles for trip: ");
        //double endMiles = scan.nextDouble();
        //System.out.println("Gallons used for trip: ");
        //double gals = scan.nextDouble();

        Car Lambo = new Car(0, 335, 9.5);
        String car1 = "Lambo";
        System.out.println("Your " + car1 + " goes " + Lambo.calculateMPG() + "        MPG");

        Car Honda = new Car(0, 24, 2);
        String car2 = "Honda";
        System.out.println("Your " + car2 + " goes " + Honda.calculateMPG() + " MPG");

        Car Eclipse = new Car(0, 48, 3);
        String car3 = "Eclipse";
        System.out.println("Your " + car3 + " goes " + Eclipse.calculateMPG() + " MPG");

        CarFleet coolCars = new CarFleet(Lambo, Honda, Eclipse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```
CarFleet(Car first, Car second,Car third) {
 this.car1 = first;
 this.car2 = second;
 this.car3 = third;
}
```

Comment: @Edwin right, somehow car1 mapped to first in mind :)

Comment: Jigar, completely understandable, expecially since 1, 2, 3 and first, second, thrid are really different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
 CarFleet(first, second, third){
```

Basically, you defined a constructor, but gave the compiler no information about what *Type* a `first`, `second`, and a `third` are.

The solution is to use a

```
 CarFleet(Car first, Car second, Car third) {
```

which now specifies the *Type* of the each variable.